# Setting template parameter default value

Tags: swift

I have written this class :

```
class Queue<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: Queue<T>?

    init(_ items: Any...)
    { 
        self.value = items[0]
    }
```

However I was wondering is there a way to implement the constructor  by setting some default value for the parameter "value".I know if I decalre it as "  var value: T?" it will be ok , but is there any "hacky" solution with the current code in the constructor to set some default value, it doesn't matter what it is , cause I want to make object like this : var obj = Queue() , cause currently Queue() crashes

Comment: You declared a generic type - i.e. `T` is free to assume any type, so what value do you want to set it then?

Comment: Whatever it is, I figured out that if something calles Queue() since it is varargs it passes zero arguments however i am calling items[0] and it crashes at Runtime

Comment: The design mistake you're making here is that you're exposing the nodes in your linked list as public API. Instead, you should have a parent `LinkedList` (or `Queue`, in your case) struct, which encapsulates a reference to the head/tail `LinkedListNode`. That way, an empty list can be modeled with a `nil` value for the `LinkedList.head`.

Comment: I agree but in this situation is there a way to do it , without wrapping up the class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that you will set the value and would rather not deal with Optionals, you could use a `!` to declare an implicitly unwrapped optional

```
class Queue<T> {
   var value: T!

   // ...
}
```

Here's more on this on [docs.swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID334)

Comment: The idea is not to change var value :T

Comment: What do you mean by not change it? It's still the same generic type `T`, and it won't ask you to provide any value. But of course, you'd need to be careful not to use it or it will crush at runtime

Comment: I mean if the signature stays like that var value: T , something else to change so Queue() works,  like creating extension or something else

Comment: In the initializer, you check if `items.count > 0`. Other than that, I'm unclear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: if I check items.count > 0 swift complains that : "self.value" is not initialized . So my goal is without changing the class property signature "  var value: T" to tell somehow that when someone calls Queue() to set the "self.value" some default value

Comment: It won't complain if you use `!`, which is what I suggested. You could've set a default value, if you knew the type. But you don't know what `T` would be. For example, if T was some type `struct Foo {}`, what would an appropriate default value be? The only other thing you could do is set it to `nil`, but that would make it an optional `T?`, unless you use `T!`

Answer (score 0):

The design mistake you're making here is that you're exposing the nodes in your linked list as public API. Your `Queue<T>` class models a node, and naturally, a link list node must contain a value. Otherwise, it's not really a node of the list, is it?

Instead, you should have a parent `LinkedList` (or `Queue`, in your case) struct, which encapsulates a reference to the head/tail `LinkedListNode`. That way, an empty list can be modeled with a `nil` value for the `LinkedList.head`.

Here's how I would do this:

```
struct LinkedList<T> {
    class Node {
        let value: T
        let next: Node?

        init(value: T, next: Node?) {
            self.value = value
            self.next = next
        }

        convenience init?(head: T?, tail: ArraySlice<T>) {
            guard let head = head else { return nil }
            self.init(
                value: head,
                next: Node(head: tail.first, tail: tail.dropFirst())
            )
        }
    }

    var head: Node?

    init(_ elements: T...) {
        self.init(elements)
    }

    // ugh, you can't forward a vararg in Swift, so you need to have this overload >_>
    init(_ elements: [T]) {
        self.head = Node(head: elements.first, tail: elements.dropFirst())
    }
}

extension LinkedList: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        guard let head = self.head else { return "LinkedList[empty]"}

        let allNodes = sequence(first: head, next: { $0.next })

        let body = allNodes
            .map { String(describing: $0.value) }
            .joined(separator: ", ")

        return "LinkedList[\(body)]"
    }
}

print(LinkedList(1, 2, 3)) // => LinkedList[1, 2, 3]
```

Then I would implement `Queue<T>` as just a basic wrapper around a `LinkedList<T>`

```
struct Queue<T> {
    var list: LinkedList<T>

    init(_ initialElements: T...) {
        self.list = LinkedList(initialElements)
    }

    mutating func push(_ newElement: T) {
        let newHead = LinkedList.Node(value: newElement, next: self.list.head)
        self.list.head = newHead
    }

    mutating func pop() -> T? {
        guard let head = self.list.head else { return nil }

        self.list.head = head.next

        return head.value
    }
}

var q = Queue(3, 2, 1)
print(q) // => Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[3, 2, 1])

q.push(4); print(q) // => Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[4, 3, 2, 1])
q.push(5); print(q) // => Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

print(q.pop(), q) // => Optional(5) Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[4, 3, 2, 1])
print(q.pop(), q) // => Optional(4) Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[3, 2, 1])
print(q.pop(), q) // => Optional(3) Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[2, 1])
print(q.pop(), q) // => Optional(2) Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[1])
print(q.pop(), q) // => Optional(1) Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[empty])
print(q.pop(), q) // => nil Queue<Int>(list: LinkedList[empty])
```